# Pointer to a variable and pointer to an array of one element

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing a socket programming application. C++ and Java as two ends. My system
is in Java and applications using my system uses C++.

I receive a pointer from C++ which holds some data, it could be a variable or an array. 
There is another variable nrOfData which tells how many elements the pointer contains.
I have to fill an Object of type String or String[] accordingly.
**But my problem is, nrOfData==1 then there is posibility for both a varaible or array(array containing one element)**
I am giving a sample program here(tried to get more similar one)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void func(string **strPtr)
{
  if(someCondition)
  {
     *strPtr = new string;
  }
  else
  {
     *strPtr = new string[1];
  }
}

int main()
{
   string *strPtr;
   func(&strPtr);
   /* I have to fill a variable and send to next level 
   strPtr contains one element in both cases. How could i determine whether
   I need to fill String or String[]*/
}
```

I should be strict to the requirement.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: First, stop using `new`. Then, are you sure you can't drop the requirement of mixing arrays and non-arrays? That causes far more trouble than you will ever need.

Comment: Maybe just use `std::vector`s, and pass references to those around? Vectors can contain zero or more elements, and you can just `std::vector::size` to get the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No I can not drop the requirement. And the program above is not the one that i am using.. I have written a similar one. Please ignore whether i used new or malloc.

Comment: *Desperately looking for "too localized" close reason*

Comment: @srikanth: The point is that you shouldn't be manually dealing with dynamic allocation at all - don't use `new` or `malloc`. Instead, simply return `std::vector<std::string>` to fix both the ambiguity over what the raw pointer points to, and the memory leak.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "sizeof()" operator which is helpful in determining pointer to an array or pointer to a variable. When we pass an array name to "sizeof()", it gives the total size of array in bytes while when we pass a plain pointer it gives the address length.

Comment: `sizeof(pointer)` is pretty senseless, and furthermore `sizeof` is implementation defined. you are guaranteed that `sizeof(T[1]) != sizeof(T[2])` but not that `sizeof(T[1]) != sizeof(T)`